# Calling a function that is inside another function

Tags: php, arrays, function, fatal-error

I have following files:

1. `arrayLoader.php`
2. `chooseProgram.php`

I want to call a function from `chooseProgram.php` that is inside another function in `arrayLoader.php`.

Here's the error message I'm getting:

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function loadTitles() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\chooseProgram.php on line 6

**arrayLoader.php**

```
function arrayLoader() {
    $arrayLoad = (file_get_contents("../files/TEMP_Array"));
    function loadTitles() {
        return $arrayLoad;
    }
    return;
}
```

**chooseProgram.php**

```
require('../tools/arrayLoader.php');
print "<pre>";
print_r(arrayLoader()->loadTitles());
print "</pre>";
```

I've googled, but I either don't understand what's going on, or what I've tried doesn't work.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to declare arrayLoader as a class instead of a function. Here is a link I think would help you accomplish what you are trying to do: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php. Good luck!

Comment: You don't have to use `->` to call a function declared inside another function, just the function name (and arguments if any) will do it. But make sure that the function inside which it is declared is called first. And also, in your code you can't really use `$arrayLoad` inside that function because it's out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

function loadTitles is dependent on arrayLoader so you should first call arrayLoader  and then loadTitles .

ie. It will work.

```
    <?php
    abc();
    xyz();
       function abc(){
        echo "abc";
        function xyz(){
            echo "xyz";
        }
       }
    ?>
```

and it will not work

```
    <?php
    xyz();
       function abc(){
        echo "abc";
        function xyz(){
            echo "xyz";
        }
       }
    ?>
```

because xyz is not defined untill abc is not called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the point of having nested function but this can be done by changing parent function to a class:

**arrayLoader.php**

```
class arrayLoader {

   function loadTitles() {
       $arrayLoad = (file_get_contents("../files/TEMP_Array"));
       return $arrayLoad;
   }
}
```

**chooseProgram.php**

```
require('../tools/arrayLoader.php');
$obj=new arrayLoader;
$result=$obj->loadTitles();
print "<pre>";
print_r($result);
print "</pre>";
```